# Should I free global memory after GlobalRealloc?

Tags: c, winapi

I just want to check whether I understood meaning of `GlobalReAlloc` function correctly. Shortly, `GlobablRealloc` changes size or memory object or its attributes. I have following questions:

```
 HGlobal old_mem = GlobalAlloc(...);
 HGlobal new_mem = GlobalReAlloc(12345, old_mem, 0); // Should I free old_mem?
```

1. Should I free old memory object after reallocing? As I understood function just changes memory object itself and returns updated memory object. Please, correct me if I am wrong
2. Should I free old memory object in the case of failed reallocation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, if the function succeeded, the old memory is now invalid, the contents were copied to the newly allocated area, and you should use the new pointer from now on. So if the function succeed, do not free the old memory
2. If the function fails, no changes were done. This means that the old pointer is still valid and you can use it. Now, if you want to free the old pointer, you can. Generally, the state of the program now is the same as before you called `GlobalReAlloc`.